# chart series names are not shown until select data in right click menu is clicked and another series is selected

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I've created a chart in excel which needs to refresh when there is a change in pivot slicer selection. Because a dynamic trend line (based on user defined trend values)has to be added, haven't created a pivot chart but selecting chart data from a range that gets updated when pivot slicer selection changes. Chart refresh based pivot slicer selection is done through VBA. It works fine without the trend line. But when trend line is selected and pivot slicer selection is changed, randomly I get 1004 error when the trend line is referred to by it's name i.e. ".SeriesCollection(name of the trend line)". While inspecting I found that the chart series names are somehow not updating (below screenshot).

[image]

Select Data Source Window

[image]

When I click on any other series the chart refreshes immediately and the series names appear (below screenshot)

[image]

I've tried using chart.refresh, chart.activate but none works. Alternatively, if I save the excel, close and open it I can see the charts normally but that's not a solution for me.

Kindly somebody help me overcome this issue.

Comment: Could you tell us a little about the structure of your data, and how the VBA updates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using pivots to get the data and using formulae to get the data from the pivot into a named range. When pivot slicer is changed I'm refreshing the charts using the named range as the source (as shown in the below code).

```
Sub ChartRefresh(ByVal chrtNm As String, Optional ByVal targetFlag As String)
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Set srcRng = ThisWorkbook.Names(chrtNm).RefersToRange
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs").ChartObjects(chrtNm).Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=srcRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .Refresh
        If targetFlag = "Yes" Then
            Call TargetShow(chrtNm)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When trend line is selected I'm adding the trend line values from a different range as a new series (below code) which is creating the problem.

```
Sub TargetShow(ByVal chrtNm As String)
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Set srcRng = ThisWorkbook.Names(chrtNm).RefersToRange
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs").ChartObjects(chrtNm).Chart
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=srcRng.Offset(0, -1).Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, 1), rowcol:=xlColumns, SeriesLabels:=True
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        On Error Resume Next
        With .SeriesCollection("Target")
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                Err.Clear
                MsgBox "Chart Refresh Error. Saving and Closing. Please re-open."
                Call TurnOn
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

I've resolved this by adding the trend line data to the named range itself (please see the below code).

```
Sub ChartRefresh(ByVal chrtNm As String, Optional ByVal targetFlag As String)
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Set srcRng = ThisWorkbook.Names(chrtNm).RefersToRange
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BTC Graphs").ChartObjects(chrtNm).Chart
        With .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count)
            .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        End With
        .SetSourceData Source:=srcRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .Refresh
'        If targetFlag = "Yes" Then
'            Call TargetShow(chrtNm)
'        End If
        If targetFlag = "Yes" Then
            With .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count)
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
                .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .DataLabels.Orientation = xlHorizontal
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```